# Split text by whitespaces

Tags: c++, qt

I have text file with some text information and i need to split this text at spaces and all word push into List.

I make so:

```
 QStringList list = line.split(" ");

  for (int i = 0; i < list.count(); i++){

      table.push_back(list[i]);
      this->ui->textEdit->setText(list[i]);
  }
```

In line i have my text. But when i test this code i get all text, but not by the word.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post an example input text along with the expected and acutal output. This way we can see exactly what you mean :)

Comment: line is a QString right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try it with:

```
line.split(QRegExp("\\s"));
```

Answer (score 1):

istream will already split according to whitespace. So an easy way to do this is

```
std::istream & txttosplit=X;///X is istringstream, or ifstream, or cin, etc
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(txttosplit),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::back_inserter(words));
```