# Display the text according to QTextedit

Tags: qt

in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442473/split-text-by-whitespaces) i asked how to split text by whitespace, now i split it, but now i can't display this text in QTextEdit.
I make so:

```
  QStringList list = line.split(QRegExp("\\s+"));

  for (int i = 0; i < list.count(); i++){
      table.push_back(list[i]);

      this->ui->textEdit->setText(table[i]); //output text in qtextedit
  }
```

But i see clean textedit after that. But if i make for example:

```
this->ui->textEdit->setText(table[2]);
```

I see third word in QTextEdit. What's wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type is `table`? `setText` only takes a QString, which means you'll need to build a big string of your split string elements and set the Text to that.

Alternatively, you could clear the QTextEdit and append every string in `table`.

Comment: table has QVector<QString> type

Comment: @Stefan thank you very much, you very helped me!


This is work:
this->ui->textEdit->append(list[i]);